# Preprocessor: generate functions with dynamic name. Multiple definition issues

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor

I got a preprocessor macro that is generating functions and variables based on a macro parameter.

Calling the macro sequently with A, B the macro would generate something like

```
Inst* AActivate() { ... }
bool Atemp;

Inst* BActivate() { ... }
bool Btemp;
```

As the macro is defined within a header file, I get linker errors informing me about already defined symbols.
I'm using #pragma once but I guess the problem lies in implementing the functions within the header.

Here's the macro:

```
    #define REGISTER(ns, id, type) \
        Inst* type##Activate() { return new type(); }\
        bool type##temp = RegisterType(ns << 8 | id, &type##Activate);
```

Now I wondered how to deal with such issues.
My first idea was the usage of some #define-Guards but obviously this would require nested #defines, which is not possible in C++.
I read about a possible solution with boost but unfortunaetly, I'm not able to use these libraries.

Any idea?

Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your macro generates function *definitions* in the header, and like any normal function, non-inlined functions in headers violate ODR if the header gets included in more than one translation unit. So just make the generated functions inline.

For the global varibales the ODR applies as well, you will have to declare them static or const to get internal linkage. That in turn will give you multiple independent instances of the variable, one for each translation unit the header gets included. Anyways, global variables are regarded bad style, so maybe you should think of something else.

Comment: Thank you I already tried to define the *Activate-Function inline within the #define macro but surprisingly the multiple definition error still occurs... That's wired to me

Comment: Ah nevermind, stupid me ... I compiled the wrong project file within VS. Using inline it works of course. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use the macro in a .cpp file or inline the functions. It doesn't really help that you use #pragma once because that only stops the header from being included more than once per .cpp file. When you compile several .cpp files, the functions get defined several times.

Answer (score 0):

You tagged for both, C and C++, you really should decide which one you use.

Things like that can only work (in both languages) if you have the function definitions as `inline`. You'd then have to have two macros, one for the inline definition that you would call in every header file that is to see the function.

In addition you'd have to have a second macro that is only called in one .c or .cpp file to do the "instantiation" for you. Here the syntax may be a bit different for C or C++.

In C this should look something like

```
    #define REGISTER(ns, id, type)                                          \
       inline Inst* type##Activate() { return new type(); }                 \
       extern bool type##temp

    #define INSTANTIATE(ns, id, type)                                       \
       Inst* type##Activate();                                              \
       bool type##temp = RegisterType(ns << 8 | id, &type##Activate)
```

Comment: you are not using ns anywhere. Would you mind explaining that a bit?